# Extreme Framedrops

Tags: battlefield-4, performance

Lately I got some heavy Framedrops wich make BF4 unplayable.

Usually My Sapphire R9 280X Vapor-X | i7 4770 run 100-100fps on HIGH settings, with drops downward to 60fps when there's much action.

But lately it drops down to 3 fps with no reason I can see.

Driver:
14.501.1003-141120a-177998C
Using the Driver since release with no problems until now.

[image]

Comment: I'm running NVidia, but I noticed a halving of my framerate on ultra with my 980 after what I thought was the latest driver update.  But maybe there was a BF update that did this?